# openstack nova : How to set disk capacity for compute nodes?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

When I go to create an instance with it fails because of disk capacity being insufficient. I see the following in the logs (on the previous successful allocation).

```
  u'DISK_GB': {u'used': 10, u'capacity': 15}}
```

This log fragment was produced by writing out the response from get_allocation_candidates in nova.scheduler.client.report.
I would like to set the capacity to be higher. Where do I set the capacity? What configuration file needs to be changed? ( I am not using the horizon UI to configure openstack ). The openstack quota command does not seem to help. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are creating a block storage based boot volume, nova will launch an instance which uses a local ephemeral disk, the size of which is set in the flavor that you select to boot the instance. If the storage isn't large enough for the image you are trying to launch, then I think you have a couple choices:

1. Choose a different flavor size that comes with a bigger disk specification, or
2. Launch your instance with a volume based on block storage, of a size you specify (in stead of the default ephemeral (local) disk).

For example:

```
nova boot --block-device source=image,id=IMAGE_ID,dest=volume,size=20,bootindex=0 \
  --flavor FLAVOR_ID NAME
```

That would launch a new inststance, and create a new bootable volume of size 20GB, based on the image whose ID you specify. In theory, you can also create a local ephemeral disk the same way by specifying `dest=local`, but in my environment, I can't get this to work - if I want a local disk, I have to let it use whatever is defined in the flavor parameters automatically.

Comment: thanks for answering. My flavor does specify 10 gb but the maximum limit is 15 (capacity) so I can't launch a second instance. I am using CCOW Linux images (for testing). I have 32 gb of physical RAM on the machine.

Comment: Ah, OK... I think I misunderstood the original question - I thought that the flavor size was the restriction, not total capacity. How much disk space does your physical server have? If its using LVM for openstack local storage, you may need to increase the VG size.